# Net charge of non-uniformly charged insulated sphere

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential

So assume there is an insulated sphere with a non-uniform charge density and radius $R$. It has a constant electric field of $E$.

Here is my current line of thinking:

We can pick a Gaussian surface at radius $r < R$.

That would give $ E(4 \pi r^2) = \frac{q(r)}{\epsilon_o} $, where $q(r)$ is a function which defines the charge enclosed by the Gaussian surface.

Assuming this is right (It seems too easy) can't we pick a point *r* so close to *R*, such that we can say $r=R$ in our calculations? that would give:

$q(R) = \frac{ER^2}{k_e} $

Is this right?

Comment: Do you mean that the electric field $\vec{E}$ is the same everywhere in space (direction and magnitude)?  Or is there some spherical symmetry, e.g. The magnitude of the field is the same everywhere but $\vec{E}$ points radially instead of in the same direction everywhere?

Comment: @Tony the $E$ is uniform inside the sphere, extending radially from the center. So yes, there is spherical symmetry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, you should use Gauss's law.  You pick a Gaussian surface that is a sphere concentric with the insulated sphere, with radius less than or equal to $R$.  Then you get:

$$
4\pi r^2 E = \frac{Q_{enc}(r)}{\epsilon_0}
$$

with $Q_{enc}(r)$ the charge enclosed by the surface of radius $r$.

If you pick $r = R$ you get $Q_{enc}(R) = 4\pi R^2E\epsilon_0$.

I'm not entirely comfortable that this is consistent with a physical distribution of charge.  Because $E$ is constant everywhere, it must be that $Q_{enc}(r) \propto r^2$.  But then charge density is infinite at the centre.

Comment: So it's right, but feels wrong?

Comment: @explodingfilms101: The maths is fine, but it seems to me that the problem itself is badly posed.  Constant $E$ requires infinite charge density at the centre, and I don't like that.